# Web Scraping with PHP Goutte

Tags: php, web-scraping, goutte, domcrawler

I want to get all the item name and price from this [website](https://redmart.com)

For example, i want to search for "apple"
https://redmart.com/search/apple

I use [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) for scraping the website. This is the code so far to get all item's name in the list:

```
$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://redmart.com/search/apple');

$crawler->filter('h4 > a')->each(function ($node) {
    print $node->text()."\n";
});
```

but when i run the code, it prints nothing. How to get all the item's name and price from the list?

Comment: Look at the source code of the page. As Binar said they are using react js and you can't parse html since there is nothing in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redmart.com website is using [react js](https://reactjs.org/) to generate the content. You cannot use a website scraper like Goutte. Instead, try using the developer console in Firefox or Google Chrome and see what's going on.

In this case, a url is requested (via ajax) that returns [JSON format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and is rendered by react: https://api.redmart.com/v1.6.0/catalog/search?q=apple&pageSize=18&sort=1024&variation=BETA

With PHP, you just use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on the response and you have everything you need.

Comment: where did you get this
https://api.redmart.com/v1.6.0/catalog/search?q=apple&pageSize=18&sort=1024&variation=BETA
??

Comment: from `Google Chrome's developer console`, the `Network` tab when I loaded redmart.com

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Comment: @Krisnadi you can get needed data from rest api of website. not need to scrap data from html source. check my post in below.

Answer (score 1):

Not need to scrap the web, you can just request on website rest API and use the poutput JSON, for example this is API for apple listing:

`https://api.redmart.com/v1.6.0/catalog/search?q=apple&pageSize=18&sort=1024&page=1&variation=BETA`

Comment: Ok i understand. Thank you